# How to keep browser window full screen after a location.replace?

Tags: javascript, html

On intro screen, the user has the choice of full screen thru a button. Say user chooses so, and I want to keep that status when we transition to the real app loading a new document using location.replace (path). Is this possible? (It seems the default behavior is that after the location.replace, the window jumps back to the size it was before the user hit full screen, as if it never happened.)
Thank you for your time and attention.

EDIT 1 - The question might be misleading if you haven`t dealt with full screen programmatically before. I don't have a problem passing parameters if user chose full screen or not, etc., the problem is that the browser:
1) Just goes back to non-full when a new page is loaded, even if user had gone full, and that is annoying.
2) When I try the requestFullscreen API family on the SECOND page - if user chose full screen on first - the browser tells me that full screen has to be a) requested by the user, b) that request had to be 'recent' (one day I'll know how recent :D)

EDIT 1.1 - Some reading show my problem maybe that I am turning an ELEMENT into full screen view, not the browser. Once the old page is gone, so is the element with the full screen...
Any pointers there? Can I at user's command turn the browser into full screen, so maybe it stays so on new page?  I'm no expert on this, it seems :D

Answer (score 0):

Whatever script you use to set fullscreen mode on the intro page, you could just call that again -- but conditionally -- on the "real" page. To remember that the user wants fullscreen, you can use Local Storage. So:

On the first page,

```
localStorage.setItem("fullScreenMode", "on");
```

Then on the second page,

```
let fullScreenMode = localStorage.getItem("fullScreenMode");
if(fullScreenMode == "on"){
  // Set second page to full screen here
}
```

Whenever the user resets the default behavior, you'd remember this new state by setting `localStorage.fullScreenMode` to `"off"` (or to "Starbuck" -- anything except "on").

Or you could wipe all your local storage properties with:

```
localStorage.clear();
```